# How to convert UNIX Epoch to date in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My table INV_STOCK_TIME with 4000 rows with unix epoch data in snowflake. That data needs to be converted to date. Here is sample data and the desired  output should be in 2 columns as given below

```
STOCK_RAWTIME
1617772221333
1616217315003
1601376748863

STOCK_RAWTIME STOCK_DATE    
1617772221333 2021-04-07
1616217315003 2021-03-20
1601376748863 2020-09-29
```

I could to convert value in column using either of the below command.

```
select to_char(to_timestamp_tz(1617772221333,3),'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
OR
SELECT to_char(dateadd('ms',timestamp_col,'1970-01-01'),'YYYY-MM-DD') from (select 1617772221333 as timestamp_col) as timetest;
```

I would like to pass the values of column1 STOCK_RAWTIME (unix epoch value)
to populate column2 STOCK_DATE. I'm unable to pass list of values to convert column1 records with below error

```
Format argument for function 'TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ' needs to be a string
```

Comment: What is data type of you field `STOCK_RAWTIME` are you storing data with new line separator or space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with this step in snowflake as to_date or to_timestamp works fine:

```
 alter table inv_stock_time add column stock_date date;
 update inv_stock_time set stock_date=to_date(STOCK_RAWTIME);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get this requirement with the following:

```
SELECT STOCK_RAWTIME as STOCK_RAWTIME, to_date(STOCK_RAWTIME)AS STOCK_DATE FROM (select STOCK_RAWTIME from INV_STOCK_TIME);
```